# Replacing user input keystrokes in real time (Java)

Tags: java, swing, input, time, passwords

I am trying to write a java program that will turn user input in real time into asterisks (in order to hide the information, like if the user is typing in a password), however I have no clue how to do this and I'm not even sure what the terminology for this is exactly.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: This requires more context. Is this a desktop application? An applet? Generally, store the data the user types, as the user types it, but do not display it.  Instead display whatever you consider 'safe'.

Answer (score 4):

Use a [`JPasswordField`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/passwordfield.html) for this.

[image]